# React testing library: Test attribute / prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing a React app using TypeScript. I use material-ui for my components and react-testing-library for my unit tests.

I'm writing a wrapper for material-ui's Grid component so that I always have an item.

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import withStyles, { WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import styles from "./styles";

export interface OwnProps {
  className?: string;
}

export interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles>, OwnProps {}

export interface DefaultProps {
  className: string;
}

export class GridItem extends PureComponent<Props & DefaultProps> {
  static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    className: ""
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, children, className, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid
        data-testid="grid-item"
        item={true}
        {...rest}
        className={classes.grid + " " + className}
      >
        {children}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(GridItem);
```

I want to write a unit test that checks if `item={true}`. I tried to use the helper library jest-dom's `toHaveAttribute` like this:

```
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";
import React from "react";
import { cleanup, render } from "react-testing-library";
import GridItem, { OwnProps } from "./GridItem";
afterEach(cleanup);

const createTestProps = (props?: object): OwnProps => ({
  ...props
});

describe("Parallax", () => {
  const props = createTestProps();
  const { getByTestId } = render(<GridItem {...props} />);
  describe("rendering", () => {
    test("it renders the image", () => {
      expect(getByTestId("grid-item")).toHaveAttribute("item", "true");
    });
  });
});
```

But this test fails with:

```
● GridItem › rendering › it renders the image

    expect(element).toHaveAttribute("item", "true") // element.getAttribute("item") === "true"

    Expected the element to have attribute:
      item="true"
    Received:
      null

      14 |   describe("rendering", () => {
      15 |     test("it renders the image", () => {
    > 16 |       expect(getByTestId("grid-item")).toHaveAttribute("item", "true");
         |                                        ^
      17 |     });
      18 |   });
      19 | });

      at Object.toHaveAttribute (src/components/Grid/GridItem/GridItem.test.tsx:16:40)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Tests:       1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.762s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

How can I test if an element has a certain attribute?

Comment: It's `(getByTestId("grid-item")` in one place and `(getByTestId("item")` in another. I suppose that's a typo in the question.

Comment: @estus it is :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`jest-dom` `toHaveAttribute` assertion asserts `item` *attribute* while the test tries to test `item` *prop*.

`item` prop won't necessarily result in `item` attribute, and since it's non-standard attribute it most probably won't.

`react-testing-library` propagates functional testing and asserts resulting DOM, this requires to be aware of how components work. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v3.3.2/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.js#L220), `item` props results in adding a class to grid element.

All units but tested one should be mocked in unit tests, e.g.:

```
...
import GridItem, { OwnProps } from "./GridItem";

jest.mock("@material-ui/core/Grid", () => ({
  default: props => <div data-testid="grid-item" className={props.item && item}/>
}));
```

Then it could be asserted as:

```
  expect(getByTestId("grid-item")).toHaveClass("item");
```

Comment: Same error message. It still says that it gets `null`.

Comment: `● GridItem › rendering › it is an item

    expect(element).toHaveAttribute("item") // element.hasAttribute("item")

    Expected the element to have attribute:
      item
    Received:
      null` Is the error message that comes up. How can I test whether the element has the attribute `item=true`?

Comment: I see. Assertion message is misleading. `null` means that there's no attribute at all. The problem is it won't have `item` *attribute*. I updated the answer to explain that. If you want to test actual code (e.g. props) rather than its effects on DOM I'd suggest to switch to Enzyme.

Answer (score 11):

If someone is still having this issue I solved it this way:

```
it('Check if it is a materialUI Grid item', () => {
    //Rendering the component in a constant.
    const { container } = render(<YourComponent />); 
    //Accessing the grid wrapper. In this case by the attribute you provided.
    const grid = container.querySelector('[data-testid="grid-item"]'); 
    //What we are expecting the grid to have.  
    expect(grid).toHaveClass('MuiGrid-item');
})
```

Notes:

1. I noticed that in the code item it's been declared as a string and not as a boolean: item='true', which will trigger a warning when you run the test. item={true} is the correct way of declaring it. Actually in material UI when you write *item* inside a grid its of course by default true, in my opinion is not necessary.
2. item is a class inside material UI Grid as the previous answer correctly suggested. So by that the correct class name should be refered in this case is 'MuiGrid-item'.

Comment: how would I test the value of the `href` attribute?

Comment: I believe you can access any attribute with dot syntax. This worked for me for testing that a button is disabled:

`const btnSave = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' });`
`expect(btnSave.disabled).toEqual(true);`

so maybe something like `expect(elem.href).toEqual('https://my-href.com');` will work for you.

Comment: @chovy please, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76270061/9936102

Answer (score 5):

I had a different case, but the title of the question brought me here. So, if you want to check if a rendered element has a particular attribute value, you can use the `getAttribute` method on the found element:

```
  it('should have red fill', () => {
      const color = 'red';
      const { container } = render(<YourComponent color="red" />);

      expect(container.querySelector('your-selector').getAttribute('fill')).toBe(color);
  });
```

More info here: https://www.wilbertom.com/post/react-testing-library-testing-a-node-attribute/