# Using react-testing-library and Jasmine

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, react-testing-library

I am playing around with react-testing-library and see whether we should use it in our project. We use `jasmine` instead of `jest`. I am wondering is `react-testing-library` can be easily be used with `jasmine` (it should be ok...)

Most of the examples I see around are with `jest`. Are there any caveats in using `react-testing-library` with `jasmine`? Are there some examples?

Thank you

Comment: It should work fine, `react-testing-library` is just a DOM testing framework and it's decoupled from `jest` or any other framework. The examples show `jest` because it's what the majority of the React community uses.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I'll just go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `react-testing-library` with Jasmine or other alternatives is that `react-testing-library` renders components closely to how they would behave in a browser. Unlike Enzyme, `react-testing-library` doesn't provide functionality for isolated and fine-grained tests like shallow rendering and accessing component internals like props.

It's expected that all components that shouldn't be rendered as is should be mocked (here's Jest [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53133944/3731501)), `react-testing-library` doesn't provide any functionality for it, a way they are mocked are at the discretion of a developer. Jasmine doesn't provide ways to mock modules and requires to use third-party solutions like `rewire`. Jest provides the functionality for module mocking, including `babel-jest` transform to hoist module mocks when they are used with `import`.

`react-testing-library` uses DOM. It's expected that JSDOM should be used if a test runs in Node. Jest natively sets up JSDOM, while a developer needs to set it up manually with Jasmine. It's preferable to run tests in Node rather than in a browser because this way modules can be dynamically mocked due to how Node `require` works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very informative. I'll have a look at jasmine/rewire mocking capabilities